# Switching OS remotely using TeamViewer

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7. Windows 7 is automatically booted (default in the bootloader). On both OS I have TeamViewer installed.

When I'm working remotely and want to switch to Ubuntu I have to reboot the PC but then automatically Windows is booted again (I'm not in front of the PC, so I cannot use the bootloader). How can I in such a case switch to Ubuntu, i.e. starting Ubuntu? And how can I switch back to Windows?

Comment: Basically your question seems to be about how to set the default OS to be loaded on (re)boot. For that it might be nice to list if you use BIOS or if you use UEFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your current boot manager.

---

If this is the Windows boot manager, then this can be done by a command
run in Admin mode similar to this :

```
bcdedit /bootsequence e {975a8204-9658-11dd-993e-9aea7965e9da}
```

The `bootsequence` parameter is
[defined](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29)
as :

> Specifies a one-time display order to be used for the next boot. This command is similar to the /displayorder option, except that it is used only the next time the computer starts. Afterwards, the computer reverts to the original display order.

You may find the identifier to use by running `bcdedit` without parameters.

You could this way setup Windows as the default boot,
and run bcdedit when you wish to boot Linux.

For more information see this
[Microsoft tip](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700231.aspx).

---

If the boot manager is grub and you are using EFI as the BIOS,
you may use under Linux the command
[efibootmgr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) :

```
efibootmgr -n XXXX
```

where XXXX is the item number of Windows from the boot list.
To find out the number for your Linux installation(s), just use efibootmgr with no options (or efibootmgr -v if you want to see details).
The number will be something like 0001 or 0002 in most cases.

You could then setup Linux as your default boot, just running Windows
once by using this command.

Comment: My boot manager is grub but I want Windows as my default boot and just running Linux once. Is this also possible?

Comment: bcdedit may be able to do it - [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2011/06/10/mdt-2012-beta-1-uefi-support/) says on an EFI system it manipulates the nvram rather than the BCD file. Otherwise, you may be able to use the free [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) - the command-line version is commercial ($29.95) but you may not need it.

Comment: What about the case when multiple Windows installations are on different hard drives? Would bcdedit let you choose which one to boot in on reboot?

Comment: @Temuri: Every installations you can boot from can be set by bcdedit.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/285755/boot-to-windows-once-from-grub-then-back-to-ubuntu-on-next-boot) but the other way around.
Assuming you have remote access on both Operating Systems, if you change Ubuntu to be your default boot you can boot back to windows using [grub-reboot](http://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot) (My [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/285755/boot-to-windows-once-from-grub-then-back-to-ubuntu-on-next-boot) has more details).

Comment: Thanks, that's looking interesting. Is this also possible the other way round?